# Computer Networks & Distributed Systems

Tags: networking, distributed-system

I am hoping to develop a chat program that will allow two people to communicate over a TCP or a UDP connection, basically with a client and a server.

Could anyone please suggest some books I could use that would cover such topics and perhaps also contains tutorials also.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: From the help centre: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read this book (http://professionalxmpp.com/), it describes the whole chatting stack, frontend and backend along with XMPP protocol explanation, and how to use it to make your chatting application.

let me know if that what you want .. Good luck!

**Edit**

Also, a good list of books that might help you on the same topic: http://xmpp.org/resources/books/

Comment: These look like very well laid out books indeed. Thank you.